# What is the lowest version Android Emulater so start times are lower

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

The question is in the title but I know higher version emulators take ages to start and it really is taking to long :(

Comment: Use an intel image and enable snapshots. Also, 2-3 minutes is not "ages."

Answer (score 1):

You can use Genymotion. It's free for personal use. And it works with VirtualBox and it can saves you a lot of time!!
http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: I also use VirtualBox and Genymotion.  The emulator takes about 20 seconds to start on my older XP system.

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator is painfully slow regardless of version, but your goal shouldn't be to get the emulator to load faster, it should be to write quality software.

Your best bet is to use a device for development, which will be much quicker than the emulator. Otherwise, launch the emulator once and leave it open while you develop.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, all of the emulators take ages to start.

To sort of answer your question though, the earliest system image you can load is from Android 2.3.3 (API 10) and is the `Intel x86 Atom System Image`

Get yourself an Android phone and save yourself some time though.